# How to get the filename

Tags: c++, vector, filenames, wstring, file-copying

I want to get the filename from a `vector <wstring>` after the search operation i want to copy all the files on the `vecAviFiles` to another path (for example D:\Test).

```
 int main()
    {
      int                      iRC         = 0;
      std::vector<std::wstring> vecAviFiles;
      std::wstring fileCopiedDestination = L"D:\\";





  // Search 'c:' for '.avi' files including subdirectories
  iRC = SearchDirectory(vecAviFiles, L"c:\\", L"doc");
  if(iRC)
  {
    std::cout << "Error " << iRC << std::endl;
    return -1;
  }

  // Print results
  for(std::vector<std::wstring>::iterator iterAvi = vecAviFiles.begin(); iterAvi != vecAviFiles.end(); ++iterAvi)
    {

        std::wcout << *iterAvi << std::endl;
        copy_file(*iterAvi,fileCopiedDestination + path::filename(*iterAvi));

    }

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is in this function (it's not working) of the boost library `copy_file(*iterAvi,fileCopiedDestination + path::filename(*iterAvi));` how can i get the filename to add it to the `fileCopiedDestination` path.
or how can i do the samething using this function from the `WIN API`

```
CopyFileW(Input.c_str(),filename(Input.c_str()) , TRUE);
```

I think that everything is clear.

Comment: Can you be more specific about "not working"? Does it not compile or does it not copy?

Comment: @pourjour See my answer; I've fixed the compilation error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you are looking for:

```
path destination = fileCopiedDestination / path(*iterAvi).filename();
copy_file(*iterAvi, destination);
```

It would probably be better if you stored `vecAviFiles` as a `vector<path>`, then the code would be a little shorter:

```
path destination = fileCopiedDestination / iterAvi->filename();
```